# How to create dynamic two dimensional array in jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create global two dimensional array in jquery or javascript

My function is like this

```
<script>

var globalArray[0] = new Array();

function createArray(){

    alert(globalArray[0]);         
}

</script>

<div><input type='button' value='save' onclick='createArray();'> </div>
```

On click of that button I am getting this error `"globalArray[0] is undefined"`

How can I create global dynamic multi dimensional array.

Comment: Is that dot `$.("#uname")` a typo?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: @gdoron Seems like simple element pushing but in a bit strange way.

Comment: index never changes, so why is it even there? also `uname` is undefined. Lack of details is causing more questions than answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (!globalArray[index]) 
    globalArray[index] = []; // init the array.

globalArray[index].push(name);
```

You have a typo with the dot:

```
$.("#uname").val();
```

Change to:

```
$("#uname").val();
```

What are you trying to do with this code?

---

**Update:** (The question was totally edited.)

Your code:

```
var globalArray[0] = new Array();
```

`globalArray[0]` is invalid  variable name, you need first to declare the array:

```
var globalArray = []; // Array literal.
globalArray[0] =  [] // The element at position 0 is new an array.
```

Comment: Just `globalArray[index].push(uname)`.

Comment: I updated my question. What ever you posted is not resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

Intead of

```
if(loop == 0){
 globalArray[index][0] = uname;
}else{
  globalArray[index][loop++] = uname;
}
```

Use this

```
if(loop > 0){
    globalArray[index][loop++] = uname;     
}else{
    globalArray[index][0] = uname;      
}
```

Comment: i haven't even done anything yet

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "yet"?

Comment: no activity i mean wont do it either not greedy for votes ups and downs

Comment: I updated my question. please check it